# Carrierwave: resize images from assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

I have a bunch of images inside my assets folder. They are categorized: a folder name matches with a model name, which represets a category. I have no struggle when listing them like a gallery, but I heed each image to be resized. 
I have already installed RMagick and Carrierwave. I have configured `ImageUploader` class:

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::RMagick
  storage :file

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  version :thumb do
    process :resize_to_fill => [128, 128]
  end
end
```

I have added a column to my model and mounted an uploader:

```
# from db/schema.rb
# path leads to an image inside assets folder
create_table "foos", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "path",       null: false
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  t.string   "image"
end
# app/models
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end
```

I tried to use `image_tag foo.image_url(:thumb)` inside my template, but it doesn't work. What did I miss?

Comment: You'll need actual records in database with files names for that model and those ids.

Comment: @Babar I already have actual records with urls for each of the files.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<%= image_tag @foo.image.thumb.url %>
```